# On multiple api-requests old request processing stop

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, rest

i have created and rest-api in core java.
this api process large number of data then returns excel file.
now the issue i'm facing is when i send single request from postman the excel contains complete data. but when i hit multiple request like 3 requests using postman the excel in first two requests contains incomplete data (only 40-60 records instead of 100) but for last request the excel again contains complete data.
it seems when ever i get new request the processing for old stops.

the api code

```
    @Path("dynamictest")
    @POST
    @Produces(XLSX)
    public Object getDynamicExcelReports(ReportParams params)
            throws SQLException, IOException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        params.setUserId(getUserId());
        if (params.getMail()) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();

                    attachment.setFileName("report.xlsx");
                    attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                            Dynamic.getDynamicExcelReporttest(params).toByteArray(), "application/octet-stream")));

                    Context.getMailManager().sendMessage(
                            params.getUserId(), "Report", "The report is in the attachment.", attachment, User.class, null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.warn("Report failed", e);
                }
            }).start();
            return Response.noContent().build();
        } else {
            return Response.ok(Dynamic.getDynamicExcelReporttest(params).toByteArray())
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, CONTENT_DISPOSITION_VALUE_XLSX).build();
        }
    }
```

the excel write function

```
    public static ByteArrayOutputStream processExcelV2test(Collection<DynamicReport> reports, ReportParams params, RpTmplWrapper rpTmplWrapper,
            Date from, Date to, boolean isDriverReport) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException, SQLException {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        List<RpTmplTblWrapper> tblListWrapper = new ArrayList(rpTmplWrapper.getRpTmplTblWrappers());
        tblListWrapper.sort(Comparator.comparing(tblWrapper -> tblWrapper.getRpTmplTbl().getPosition()));
        tblListWrapper.forEach((tblWrapper) -> {  //loop for multiple sheets
            try {
                String sheetName = tblWrapper.getRpTmplTbl().getLabel().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "|");
                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);

                /**setting data in rows and columns**/

            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        });
        
        Logger.getLogger(DynamicExcelUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "workbook completed");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(stream);
        workbook.close();
        return stream;
    }
```

any help or suggestion will be helpful
thanks

Comment: Do these requests provdes the same params? I am interested in providing the param which is responsible for ```getMail()``` function to response with ```true```.

Comment: yes with exactly same params and consider ```getMail() = false```, so excel sent in response not in email

Comment: even if ```getMail() = true``` for multiple calls the behavior remain same in early request incomplete data in excel and for last request complete data

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: yes using debug logs because issue with multiple request in same time, with single request it works fine, and with debugging didn't get any thing helpful.